# Updating gems on my mac - two versions of bundler installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I had tons of gems on my local machine which I were installed before and after RVM, so I decided to wipe them all and reinstall.  Everything seemed to go ok, except bundler:

```
gem list
.....
bundler (1.1.3, 1.0.22)
```

I don't know why 1.0.22 is still there, and I can't figure out how to get rid of it!

```
$ gem cleanup
  Cleaning up installed gems...
  Attempting to uninstall bundler-1.0.22
  Unable to uninstall bundler-1.0.22:
    Gem::InstallError: gem "bundler" is not installed
  Clean Up Complete

$ gem uninstall bundler-1.0.22
  INFO:  gem "bundler-1.0.22" is not installed
```

**UPDATE 1**
Path info as requested by Andrew

```
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/
```

Comment: What is the output of `gem contents bundler -v 1.0.22`? (Just the common pathname of them is sufficient)

Comment: Andrew - I have a similar scenario, and my common path is "/Users/USERNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.0.22/"

Comment: Going to update my answer with the requested path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's most likely happening is that the two versions of Bundler are installed in two different gemsets, one of which is inheriting from the other. `1.0.22` is probably installed in the `global` gemset (`rvm use @global`), or "root" gemset (`rvm use <ruby_version>`). Once you're in the gemset that has `1.0.22` installed, you should be able to remove it with `gem uninstall bundler`.

Comment: From what I remember you can just do `rvm use @global` and it implies the current Ruby version.

Comment: Heh, I never knew that! Editing my answer.

Comment: This worked!  Thanks :)  Did an 'rvm use @global' and then gem uninstall bundler