# Error running gem env

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I run `gem env`, I get the following error:

```
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/home/chenge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-0.9.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": undefined method `first' for #<String:0x8ec8670> (NoMethodError)
```

Could anybody help me to understand what this means? Thanks.

```
gem clean

Cleaning up installed gems...
Attempting to uninstall rvm-1.11.3.3
Unable to uninstall rvm-1.11.3.3:
    Gem::InstallError: gem "rvm" is not installed
Attempting to uninstall rubygems-bundler-0.9.2
Unable to uninstall rubygems-bundler-0.9.2:
    Gem::InstallError: gem "rubygems-bundler" is not installed
Attempting to uninstall bundler-1.1.3
Unable to uninstall bundler-1.1.3:
    Gem::InstallError: gem "bundler" is not installed


Clean Up Complete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rubygems-bundler` is out-date(0.9.2), install the latest version([1.1.0](http://rubygems.org/gems/rubygems-bundler/versions/1.1.0)) will fix that.

```
$ gem clean
$ gem install rubygems-bundler
```

I tried on my EC2 instance, it works.

Comment: You'd probably want to run `gem install rubygems-bundler; gem clean` to let Gem remove any old versions.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046321/updating-gems-on-my-mac-two-versions-of-bundler-installed

Comment: :)Really thanks. 'rvm use @global' and then gem uninstall rubygems-bundler。

Answer (score -1):

the problem may be caused by:

- incorrectly installed Ruby
- incorrectly installed RubyGem
- incorrectly installed RVM

I suggest you remove the rubygem entirely. ( `rm /home/chenge/.rvm/gems -rf` ) and then download the latest rubygem then re-install it.

Comment: I downloaded rubygems1.8.24, run ruby setup.rb, and problem still there.